While invoking third party AAR sdk in Signed Build
org.simpleframework.xml.core.InstantiationException:  Cannot instantiate class com.ecs.abc.ESignProcessor for class com.ecs.abc.ESignProcessor
Getting above error while invoking third party sdk in a Release signed build. In debug build its working fine.Above mentioned path com.ecs.abc.ESignProcessor is from third party sdks AAR.
What should i write in proguard rule to ignore this.

Well it was a Pro-guard related issue. While invoking the response was getting in XML format. So I have to add.
-keepattributes Signature, *Annotation*, EnclosingMethod

# Keep the fields with Simple XML annotations
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @org.simpleframework.xml.* <fields>;
}

# Keep the classes with Simple XML annotations
-keep class * {
    @org.simpleframework.xml.* <methods>;
    @org.simpleframework.xml.* <fields>;
}


-dontwarn javax.xml.stream.events.**

-keep public class org.simpleframework.** { *; }
-keep class org.simpleframework.xml.** { *; }
-keep class org.simpleframework.xml.core.** { *; }
-keep class org.simpleframework.xml.util.** { *; }

-keepattributes ElementList, Root

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @org.simpleframework.xml.* *;
}

-keep class com.ecs.abc.** { *; }

